# Convert SQL query to sequelize form

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I want to convert the following (as a reference) in a sequelize find() way

select * from table where (FROM_UNIXTIME(createdDate) + interval 6 hour) <= now();

Appreciate your effort guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Sequelize.where` and `Sequelize.literal` because Sequelize doesn't supprt for `interval` and an addition:

```js
const items = await table.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(Sequilize.literal('FROM_UNIXTIME(createdDate) + interval 6 hour'), '<=', Sequelize.fn('now'))
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly. its really working !